Error while adding spinnaker package to Yocto build for core-image-sato
I am working on a project for the intel-corei7-x86_64 hardware board, building the Yocto image core-image-sato.
While trying to add the spinnaker package to the Yocto build, I encountered the following error during the build process for core-image-sato:
im using meta-ros layer for including this spinnaker package.
`user@LTB-IBE2590:~/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build$ bitbake core-image-sato
Loading cache: 100% |#######################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Loaded 8602 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "intel-corei7-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.0.23"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 corei7"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
DISTRO_NAME          = "Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)"
ROS_DISTRO           = "humble"
ROS_VERSION          = "2"
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION   = "3"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "HEAD:0bffb5eed1e8c9469b9c6e0d77f959dc9ade9c6a"
meta-intel           = "HEAD:8514c60ac1a9a17ba20b17fa176119728a91dcf9"
meta-oe              
meta-python          
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-filesystems     = "kirkstone:4ad41baed6236d499804cbfc4f174042d84fce97"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:644ebf220245bdc06e7696ccc90acc97a0dd2566"
meta-freescale       = "HEAD:c525e0c19bdc46d45f71873b5f286f49abb69418"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:d5bbb487b2816dfc74984a78b67f7361ce404253"
meta-ros1-noetic     
meta-ros1            
meta-ros-common      
meta-ros2-humble     
meta-ros2            = "kirkstone:72f70f7c1147197bd1e447c03187628b4b62a738"

Initialising tasks: 100% |##################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:06
Sstate summary: Wanted 1297 Local 442 Mirrors 0 Missed 855 Current 2965 (34% match, 79% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: ament-cmake-core-native-1.3.10-1-r0 do_configure: ExecutionError('/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/temp/run.do_configure.3890', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.3890
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake/cmake-native_3.22.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.67.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/meta-ros/meta-ros-common/recipes-infrastructure/python/python3-catkin-pkg_0.4.24.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/meta-ros/meta-ros2-humble/generated-recipes/ament-package/ament-package_0.14.0-4.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/ninja/ninja_1.10.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.10.15.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['cmake-native', 'quilt-native', 'python3-catkin-pkg-native', 'ament-package-native', 'ninja-native', 'python3-native', 'curl-native', 'zstd-native', 'zlib-native', 'ncurses-native', 'bzip2-native', 'xz-native', 'libtool-native', 'libnsl2-native', 'readline-native', 'libtirpc-native', 'openssl-native', 'util-linux-libuuid-native', 'gdbm-native', 'libffi-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'python3-setuptools-native', 'python3-importlib-metadata-native', 're2c-native', 'python3-wheel-native', 'python3-pyparsing-native', 'python3-installer-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'perl-native', 'python3-setuptools-scm-native', 'python3-toml-native', 'python3-pathlib2-native', 'python3-zipp-native', 'python3-flit-core-native', 'unzip-native', 'make-native', 'python3-packaging-native', 'python3-tomli-native', 'python3-six-native', 'python3-more-itertools-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| -- Found Python3: /home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3 (found version "3.10.15") found components: Interpreter
| WARNING: Package "%s" has newlines in the description
| -- ament_cmake_core 1.3.10
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/git/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
|     from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
| ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
| CMake Error at ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
| 
|   execute_process(/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3
|   /home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/git/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
|   /home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/build/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
|   returned error code 1
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   CMakeLists.txt:19 (include)
| 
| 
| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
| See also "/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ament-cmake-core-native/1.3.10-1-r0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/meta-ros/meta-ros2-humble/generated-recipes/ament-cmake/ament-cmake-core_1.3.10-1.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1131 tasks of which 1126 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:native:/home/user/Mindteck_Projects/Irilic/kirkstone_yocto_AIMB288E/sources/meta-ros/meta-ros2-humble/generated-recipes/ament-cmake/ament-cmake-core_1.3.10-1.bb:do_configure
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.

`
I noticed the key error is:
ament-cmake-core-native-1.3.10-1-r0 do_configure: ExecutionError

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'  

To resolve this, I attempted to build the ament-package using the command:
bitbake ament-package  
bitbake ament-cmake-core-native
bitbake core-image-sato

Afterward, I retried building core-image-sato, but the result remained unchanged, and the error persists.
1: How can I resolve the missing ament_package module error?
2: Is there an additional step required to ensure the spinnaker package integrates
successfully into the Yocto build?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
